# Search string from array and reference array number

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to search a string to see if it contains a member of a string array. If the string does contain something from the array, then I want to record the index number of the array member it found, and then display it.

```
string stringToBeSearched = "I want to find item2 or item6";
string[] array = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
// Search stringToBeSearched for anything in array, then enter the array 
// member's index value into int position
int position = //array index number of item found
Console.WriteLine("{0} was found.", array[position]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare each array element with the `stringToBeSearched` using `IndexOf`.

```
string stringToBeSearched = "I want to find item2 or item6";
string[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

int position;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    string str = array[i];

    if (stringToBeSearched.IndexOf(str) >= 0) {
        position = i;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was found.", str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

// Result: 
// item2 was found.
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using Linq and Generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
       string[] array1 = "I want to find item2 or item6".Split(' ');
       string[] array2 = {"item1", "item2", "item6"};

       IEnumerable<string> results = array1.Intersect(array2,
                                                     StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

       foreach (string s in results)
          Console.WriteLine("{0} was found at index {1}.", 
                            s, 
                            Array.IndexOf(array2, s));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringToBeSearched = "I want to find item2 or item6";
string[] array = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

string firstOrDefault = array.FirstOrDefault(stringToBeSearched.Contains);
int position = firstOrDefault == null
   ? -1
   : Array.IndexOf(array, firstOrDefault);

if (position >= 0)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} was found.", array[position]);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Did not find any of the strings.");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Note that this will find the first matching string. If there are more than one you won't know about the others.